# Perdendo conexão com banco de dados. Postgress, Glassfish

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, glassfish

Apos uns 15 minutos meu sistema para de se comunicar com o banco de dados.

Log Entry Detail
Close

Timestamp
05/09/2016 21:22:30.287
Log Level
ERROR
Logger
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
Name-Value Pairs
{levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1473110550287}
Record Number
2130
Message ID
Complete Message
This connection has been closed.

local problema não acontece. Apos configurar banco remoto problema já começa. Pesquisando, descobri que é necessário criar o pool de conexão quando se trabalha com glassfish, tentei criar mas não da ping com meu banco.

Estou trabalhando com jpa, glassfish 4.1

```
 <persistence-unit name="meusistema" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://...:5432/..."/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>


  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

</properties>
```

Erro apresentado na criação do pool

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for juridicoPool. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
```

Comment: Criou a Datasource e o Pool ?

Comment: Como você se conecta ao banco? estás usando jndi ou as propriedades estão no persistence.xml?

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra estou usando as propriedades no xml. Postei na pergunta.

Comment: @DilneiCunha estava tentando criar o pool mas não consegui. Coloquei todas as informações mas não da ping. Pesquisando vi que é preciso criar um pool no glassfish, está correto?

Comment: Isso, você precisa criar a datasource + o Pool e testar o ping, quando for usar o gerenciamento de conexões pelo container seu persistence.xml muda para JTA, ex: transaction-type="JTA", eu não lembro bem mas no glassfish você vai precisar adicionar o jar(connector JDBC) do banco que deseja, acho não tenho certeza que ficava em lib/ext, já faz anos que não uso este server, mas se não conseguir avisa que vejo nas docs, abração.

Comment: @DilneiCunha quer dizer que eu não preciso obrigatoriamente usar o contêiner para gerenciar minhas conexões. Quando não uso o container o gerenciado é feito pelo entityManager? Estou usando CDI. Vou estudar mais a fundo sobre isso. Obrigado!

Comment: a noite vou instalar um glassfish, tirar prints e colocar aqui de como criar, mas assim: eu pefiro que assuntos de infraestrutura não fiquem sendo  gerenciados  por minha aplicação, prefiro que fique por conta do container, em um bom design de software não é bom a aplicação gerenciar esses recursos, baseado nisso também tem o fato Spring-Security X JAAS prefiro JAAS porque eu não levo bibliotecas para dentro do meu software cuidar de assuntos que também são de infraestrutura, no caso eu deixo o container cuidar disso para mim, mas tudo tem exceção a regra.

Comment: Sim você pode deixar a aplicação gerenciando tudo.

Comment: @DilneiCunha mudei meu banco de dados e o erro não ocorreu mais. Estava usando um banco da UolHost, mudei para amazon e o problema de desconectar não voltou a aconteceu. De qualquer forma vou configurar o pool de conexão. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: desculpe não ter postado ainda como se configura, estou abaixo de mal tempo :) e tive ajudando outros, mas vou fazer :)

Comment: @DilneiCunha Fica tranquilo. Pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi alguns exemplos na net. Salvei drive do postg no meu glassfish e o erro mudou, está com erro de porta, mas a porta estava liberada. Não fiz o teste no novo banco da amazon. Vou testar e posto o resultado. Obrigado!